# MPlot3D Image Manipulation in IPython

Tags: python, ipython, spyder, mplot3d

I am developing a Python program that involves displaying X-Y-Z Trajectories in 3D space. I'm using the Spyder IDE that naturally comes with Anaconda, and I've been running my scripts in IPython Consoles.

So I've been able to generate the 3D plot successfully and use `pyplot.show()` to display it on the IPython Console. However, when displayed in IPython, only one angle of the graph is shown. And I've read that MPlot3D can be used to create interactive plots. Am I correct in believing that I should be able to rotate and zoom the 3D graph? Or does IPython and/or the Spyder IDE not support this feature? Should I work on rotating the plot image within the script? How do I interact with this plot?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can rotate and interact with Mplot3d plots in Spyder, you just have to change the setting so that plots appear in a separate window, rather than in the IPython console. Just change the inline setting to automatic:

Tools > preferences > IPython console > Graphics > Graphics backend > Backend: Automatic

Then click Apply, close Spyder, and restart.

Answer (score 1):

I initially faced same issue
Everything seems to be alright but couldn't rotate the picture.

After toggling between graphical and automatic in
Tools > preferences > IPython console > Graphics > Graphics backend > Backend: ....

I could rotate the image